# 12 Digit company prefix on GTIN-14?

Tags: gs1-datamatrix

Is GTIN-14 valid GTIN (according to GS1) if it’s missing item reference?

Some visual depiction of what I'm inquiring about 
[image: s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but It's kind of a special corner case.  In theory you can have this case, prices to obtain a company prefix are directly linked to its size (the smaller, the wider is your range for items). Having such a case is something I saw once for a company working in this domain but not producing any items (they are software provider for pharmaceutic production lines).

So it's valid but not something you should find on real produced items.

Comment: Thanks @Mikitori , can you provide some reference to related gs1 standard explicitly stating that item reference is not required ?

Comment: quick example: you can search here http://gepir.gs1.org/index.php/search-by-gln the GLN 3779000000682. You'll see an official Key Licensee Information attributed to the company I was talking about. you can then see their official GS1 Company Prefix is 12 digits long, so no digit available for the item.